# Notification about unapprovable suggested edit

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, notifications, review-queues

Around here you need 20000 rep to edit tag wikis without being peer reviewed, but only 5000 rep to review them. If you are in between (like me) then you can propose edits but not approve your own.

I suggested a tag wiki edit tonight and the little red balloon showed up saying there was one new suggestion to approve. But when I click on it, it takes me to the list and says none are available. I think it found *my* suggested edit and is appropriately not allowing me to approve it. However it forgot to not alert me to its existence.

Can we fix that?

Comment: I've seen that on BH too.

Comment: @Sklivvz FTR I have been a mod since the new review system came out, so I can't confirm this problem still exists.

Comment: @DoubleAA We got the same issue reported elsewhere, so it's still there for sure.

Comment: @Sklivvz Is this still an issue now that the "to review bubble" accounts for other queues?