# Box counting list of posts for review doesn't seem to be true

Tags: support, bug, review-queues

The little orange box at the top of the webpage indicates that there are ten total posts awaiting review. But the list shows no posts awaiting review. Why is that? (There are no posts for review outside the range of the screen-shot).

[image: screen shot]

Comment: [Blame caching.](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/237873)

Comment: @msh210 2 hours later. Orange box score - 9; marked for my review - Zero

Comment: I think the box is for everyone. There may be posts waiting for review that you are ineligible to take action on, probably because you already did.

Comment: @Scimonster Or because you are the author of those posts (eg. someone flagged your post as not an answer)

Comment: Can we retag this as a [meta-tag:bug]? I know it's "by design," but I think it annoys pretty much everyone who ever looks at that number, which is a characteristic of a usability bug.

Comment: Retagged as bug.

Comment: similar https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1173/759