# red circle near the ikon for "Review Queues"

Tags: bug

There is a red circle near the ikon for "Review Queues" and when I click on it, it shows a red circle for "low quality" posts. When I click on that, it indicates that the Review Queue has been cleared. This seems like something that should be fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1173/759

Comment: @DoubleAA The possible dup says, "I think it found my suggested edit and is appropriately not allowing me to approve it. However it forgot to not alert me to its existence." That is not my issue. I had made no edit and have sufficient rep to edit material.

Comment: Is it still happening? It's probably a duplicate of https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: YES it is  still happening.

Comment: Happens to me all the time. Always wonder if it's a little insight into the fact that someone's probably reported one of my posts, and that's hidden in the queue but not the notifications :)